# Index(Small) equivalent for VBA, Finding the next instance instead of the same one in loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, indexing

```
Sub Random()
'if you have questions or you broke the macro, reach out to the AU DataDudes!
Dim J As Integer
Dim P As Integer
Dim V As Integer
Dim Production As Worksheet
Dim Distro As Worksheet
Dim IRowL As Integer
Dim ProwL As Integer
Dim StartRange As Range

Set Production = Worksheets("Alias Production Detail Report")
Set Distro = Worksheets("WorkList")


IRowL = Distro.Cells(Distro.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'if you changed the location of the Name in the Gracie sheet change this
ProwL = Production.Cells(Production.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'if you change the location of the name in the master sheet change this
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For J = 2 To IRowL
        For P = 2 To ProwL

            If Distro.Cells(J, 1).Value = Production.Cells(P, 6).Value Then
            If Production.Cells(P, 5).Value <> Distro.Cells((J - 1), 5).Value Then

                    Production.Cells(P, 1).EntireRow.Copy
                    Distro.Cells(J, 1).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                    Exit For
            End If
            End If
        Next P
Next J
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox ("All Done!")
```

Did a super primitive approach to a small equivalent for VBA but it will only work for instances of 2,

```
If Production.Cells(P, 5).Value <> Distro.Cells((J - 1), 5).Value
```

Can someone provide the approach/thought process regarding using small within the loop resulting can continually get the next instance instead of the same one over and over.

Comment: Are you saying that once row `P` is visited, you don't want to visit it again in your looping?

Comment: please add more details and examples of "before" and "after" scenario

Comment: yes i want to exclude any `P` that has already been imported into the new dataset.